# Relative/Responsive Images -HTML -CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two image links generated like so, Here is the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="BigLinks" href="My_Name.pdf" id="Resume" style="position: absolute; top: 264px;!important left: 17px; !important color: #0005FF"></a></li>
     <li><a class="BigLinks" href="espn.com" id="Personal_Projects" style="position:absolute; top: 51em; left: 49em; color: #0005FF"></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code..

```
#Resume{
background-image: url(Resume_Button.png);
display: block;
border: .25em solid #FF0004;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: 200%; For Removing the hyperlink (Not Clean)  
white-space:nowrap;
width: 509px;
padding-top: 5em;
padding-bottom: 5em;

}

#Resume:hover{
display:block;
border: 1em solid #FF0004;
height:15em;
overflow:hidden;
text-indent:200%;  For Removing the hyperlink (Not Clean) 
white-space:nowrap;
width:31em;
padding-top:5em;
padding-bottom:5em;
}

#Personal_Projects{
background-image:url(android-logo2.png);
display: block;
border: 0.25em solid #FF0004;
height:15em;
overflow:hidden;
text-indent:200%;  For Removing the hyperlink (Not Clean) 
white-space:nowrap;
width:31em;
padding-top:5em;
padding-bottom:5em;



}

#Personal_Projects:hover{
display: block;
border:1em solid #FF0004;
height:15em
overflow:hidden;
text-indent:200%
white-space:nowrap;
width:31em;


}
```

My problem is that I would like the two buttons to not be in the optimal position regardless of the size of a screen. AKA I would like the image position to be responsive no hard coded. With the way I coded it now it looks goo on my laptop screen however not on my larger TV screen.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems there.  Not 100% clear on what you're asking, but getting rid of the position: absolute declarations in the style attribute will reintroduce your links into the flow of the document.

Second, you're going to have difficulty getting a good result if you mix px and ems. The two don't always play nicely together.

Also, what are you trying to do with the text-indent/white-space/overflow declarations?

Comment: This is really a comment rather than an answer, but makes good suggestions that are pertinent to the (probable) issue the OP is seeking guidance on - in particular removing position absolute. For future reference, and to avoid being downvoted by other users, if you are not able to answer the question as it stands you should add comments rather than answer. Welcome to StackOverflow! I look forward to seeing more of your answers in future.

Comment: @pwdst Thank you very much for the help! I'll keep your advice in mind. Still getting the hang of things.